# Перечисление вариантов для поиска методом startsWith()

Tags: javascript, методы

```
something.startsWith(string1 + some_strings_here)
```

Как в данном случае можно перечислить несколько различных вариантов аругментов?

Приведу крайне примитивный пример

Есть 4 варианта предложений:

> Зелёныйпомидор лежал на столе
>   Зелёныйбанан лежал на столе
>   Зелёныйлимон лежал на столе
>   Красныйпомидор лежал на столе

Нужно найти только предложения про зелёные помидор и банан. На конкатенацию 0 внимания, так надо.

Comment: Интересно, а как одна строка может начинатся с нескольких вариантов?

Comment: Происходит поиск всего, что соответствует началу string1 + ещё некоторые строки. В варианте 1 "основа" + 1 "вариант" это работает нормально, но вот как сделать, скажем, 1 + 2 разных или 1+3?

Comment: регулярки вам в помощь

Answer (score 1):

Регулярки :

```js
var arr = [
  'Зелёныйпомидор лежал на столе',
  'Зелёныйбанан лежал на столе',
  'Зелёныйлимон лежал на столе',
  'Красныйпомидор лежал на столе'
];

var r = new RegExp('^Зелёный[помидор|банан]', 'i');

arr.forEach(e => {
  if (r.test(e))
    console.log(e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
something.startsWith("str1") || something.startsWith("str2")
```

Или можно использовать такую функцию

```js
console.log(StartsWith("test",["str1","str2","str3"]));
console.log(StartsWith("str2hihi",["str1","str2","str3"]));

function StartsWith(string, starts) {
   for(let st of starts) {
      if(string.startsWith(st)) {
         return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```